# ¿Como solicitar información extra a un usuario para que edite su perfil despues de haberse logueado?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

Hola que tal espero se encuentren bien:

Lo que pasa es que tengo un proyecto donde al inicio como todas las paginas tengo mi registro pidiendo datos personales a los usuarios, tales como: nombre de usuario, email, contrasena, etc. Esto por medio de un INSERT a mi tabla usuarios en mysql.

Mi pregunta es: ¿Tengo que hacer otro INSERT? o ¿solamente un UPDATE a la información que esta en blanco?, para pedir mas datos personales para que el usuario pueda editar su perfil posteriormente al registro, entiendo que aqui puedes solicitar mas información tal como: modifica tu edad, sexo,   localidad, estado civil, entre otros.

Mi tabla se llama usuarios y ahi tengo 12 campos de los cuales solamente utilize 5 para el registro del usuario y los otros estan en blanco para que posteriormente se modifiquen a peticion del usuario.

Espero que alguien pueda explicarme esta parte.

Gracias.

Comment: Hacer un UPDATE de la información que está en blanco parece una mejor opción, a no ser que lo tengas en tablas separadas (que no parece ser el caso).

Comment: Bienvenido a stackoverflow en español, puede que le interese leer esto 
[Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour), puede tratar de mejorar 
su pregunta mirando este link [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
es posible que su pregunta sea cerrada, ya que no cumple con los estándares del sitio, no se lo tome a mal. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Solamente tienes que hacer un `UPDATE` a la fila del usuario correspondiente. Si tienes la relación por *id de usuario*, solamente es que hagas el `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE usuarios SET edad=14, sexo='h', localidad='zapopan', estadocivil='soltero' WHERE id='1'
```

Comment: @Noctis Nunca uses sentencias de insersión o actualización directas (como la que muestra esta solución) para registrar información ofrecida por los usuarios. **Te expones a ataques de inyección SQL** Usa siempre sentencias preparadas.

Comment: Gracias por el consejo @quevedo